# get due for each employee paid amount

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am newbie to asp.net mvc. I have searched a lot for the following situation but couldn't find anything in c#. Please don't block me. Kindly just provide a solution because I want to learn.

1. Employee_table (which shows active employees with following attributes)
   1.1 id , name , total_due_amount , Status
2. transaction_table (which contain all transaction for all employees with following attributes)
   2.1 id , parent_id , date , labor_cost_of_week , paid , due , details

Employee controller
Employee_transaction controller

where parent id is foreign key from Employee_table I need to show the due amount of last transaction in employee table for all employees.
Feel free to ask anything in case I didn't explain.

[image: employee controller index view]
[image: transaction controller index view]

Comment: it might be just me, sorry, but I couldn't get what is the question?

Comment: Dear Amr i want to get the last transaction's due amount in main table (Employee table) e.g. i labour worked for 100$ i paid 90$ due is 10$ i need to show this in employee table under total amount column.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to figure out the exact formula which is used for the calculation. Afterwards, collect necessary data from all database and make those calculations, then return your answer.

There is probably a more sophisticated way to do this, but for you the simplest one is the best.

Basically, you send request to the controller, the method in controller accesses some other class containing all the methods for calculations and then you return a string or JSON result with the controller.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i am new to asp.net kindly provide some linq query or code to sort it out. THANKS!

Comment: you will probably be taking data from a database, so you need to take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples#sqlclient

Comment: Dear all thanks for considering the question. After brainstorming i concluded a solution of sort and filtering the data tables all transaction will be saved in same table with employees names, but again i am stuck on a problem on how to add a new transaction of an existing employee.
Any solutions please do provide that will be a great favor.